# CSS - Centering an image

Tags: html, css, scaling

So I have an image which is acting as a background and it 'scales to fill' the frame which is just how I want it, but the image is not centered and thus when the window is smaller like on a phone, the image displayed is just the edge. Here is the code I was using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Background">
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Background {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('background.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If anyone could give me some hints then that would be great. Thanks

Comment: `background-position: center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css code

```
.Background {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('background.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 100% work.

```
.Background {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    background-size: cover;
     background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("background.png") no-repeat scroll center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be beneficial to include an example of what the problem is.

Try this.

```
        .Background {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
margin-right:auto;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: url('background.png') no-repeat /* <- however you want the image to repeat */ center;
    }
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
background-position: center;
```

added to your css rule will center the background image

```
text-align:center
```

added to your div will work for all content inside, even text